# Load contacts to retrieve email address and send email

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I am new to iphone world i want to ask a question: 
There is a contact button in my IOS app, all what i want to do is when user tap on that button it opens up my phone contacts , i chose any of the email of my friend from that contacts and then i send email to that address..

I want to achieve this functionality.

I have done its vice versa using messageUI framework. At their when you tap on email a + button appears and when you click on it a contact page open you chose the email address from there. I actually want this functionality on my contact button.

When i tap contacts my phone contacts load i select a contact from there and send email to it. I dont know how to do this in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at some apple documentation like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1)? Also would help if you posted sample code.

Comment: Yes i have looked at it , but i dont want to create  extra label or any UI i just load the email address from contact and open it in email sender view

Comment: @user1583015 I'm not going to write the code for you, but in the delegate method `displayPerson:` an `ABRecordRef` is passed, where you can access array of email addresses as `ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSArray *emailAddresses = [(NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue) autorelease];
CFRelease(emailMultiValue);`. Bear in mind that there could be no email addresses or tens, so you will need to plan your UI for this.